# modify list element with list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

folks,

I want to modify list element with list comprehension. For example, if the element is negative, add 4 to it.

Thus the list

```
a = [1, -2 , 2]
```

will be converted to

```
a = [1, 2, 2]
```

The following code works, but i am wondering if there is a better way to do it?

Thanks.

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i]<0:
        a[i] += 4
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
a = [b + 4 if b < 0 else b for b in a]
```

Comment: if list a is very big, would this way cause memory problems?

Comment: I don't know.  I would guess that this creates a new list which has to be stored somewhere before it is copied over to a, so probably.

Comment: Unless you know that dataset is going to be *huge*, I wouldn't worry too much about it... Also, generator expressions can go a long way to resolving such issues (not in this case though).

Comment: @nos: If the data set is so big that it would cause memory problem (like it occupies half the RAM + Swap space), may be you shouldn't use a Python list in the first place. (e.g. NumPy or [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html)).

Answer (score 8):

If you want to change the list *in-place*, this is almost the best way. List comprehension will create a new list. You could also use `enumerate`, and assignment must be done to `a[i]`:

```
for i, x in enumerate(a):
  if x < 0:
    a[i] = x + 4
```

Answer (score 3):

This version is older, it would work on Python 2.4

```
>>> [x < 0 and x + 4 or x for x in [1, -2, 2]]
0: [1, 2, 2]
```

For newer versions of Python use [conditional expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) as in Adam Wagner or BenH answers

Answer (score 2):

Why mutate, when you can just return a new list that looks like you want it to?

```
[4 + x if x < 0 else x for x in [1, -2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 b = [x + 4 if x < 0 else x for x in a]
```

Or if you like `map` more than a list comprehension:

```
 b = map(lambda x: x + 4 if x < 0 else x, a)
```